# Accuracy stays constant while training a keras model. What may be the reason?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have been trying to train a simple skip gram word2vec model using keras.
After training for some time, i noticed the accuracy is not changing at all

Things ive tried:
1. Ive tried changing the optimizers to adam, rmsprop.
2. For sgd, ive tried changing the learning in steps from 1.0 to 0.000001
3. Ive tried changing the batch size.

Still no luck.

Here's some of the code.

```
def make_model(self,vocab_size=256,vec_dim=100):
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(vec_dim,activation="sigmoid",input_dim=vocab_size))
    model.add(Dense(vocab_size,activation="sigmoid"))
    sgd=SGD(lr=1.0)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=sgd,metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

def _get_callbacks(self):
    earlystop=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",min_delta=0.0001,patience=10,verbose=2)
    checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint("checkpt.hdf5",period=10,verbose=2)
    reducelr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",factor=0.1,patience=5,verbose=2)
    return [earlystop,checkpoint,reducelr]

def train(self,model,X,y):
    model.fit(X,y,nb_epoch=1000,callbacks=self._get_callbacks(),validation_split=0.1,verbose=2,batch_size=300)
    model.save("model.hdf5")
```

X is a one hot vector of len 256 for every word

y in a one hot vector of len 256 representing the skip word in the context of X.

so for instance if the sequence is [2,6,5,7,9]
X will be
[5,5,5,5,7,7,7...]

y will be
[2,6,7,9,6,5,9...]
and so on for every word in the sequence.

This is what happens when i try to train:

```
9s - loss: 4.5012 - acc: 0.1794 - val_loss: 4.5873 - val_acc: 0.1327
Epoch 2/1000

9s - loss: 4.2679 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 4.8339 - val_acc: 0.1327
Epoch 3/1000

9s - loss: 4.2363 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 4.7040 - val_acc: 0.1327
Epoch 4/1000

9s - loss: 4.2102 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 4.6947 - val_acc: 0.1327
Epoch 5/1000

9s - loss: 4.1882 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 4.6625 - val_acc: 0.1327
Epoch 6/1000

9s - loss: 4.1777 - acc: 0.1801 - val_loss: 4.6303 - val_acc: 0.1327
```

I ve waited for a about 50 epochs and the acc still does not change.

Any idea what i am doing wrong? Ive faced this problem everytime ive used keras even when training other models like language modelling using RNNs text generation using LSTMs.

Comment: It's possible that there's nothing wrong, and that is the best accuracy you can get from your data and model.

Comment: @thc people have got more than 90% accuracy on the skip gram using a single hidden layer neural network. I agree that the data might be the problem. It seems like it is too less for classifying into 256 categories. But this problem has surfaced even on other models and data. I could usually get around after changing the batch size. But im really confused how batch size can have such a drastic effect. And in this case, even the batch size tweak doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing activation from `sigmoid` to `ReLU`? Maybe the layer responses are getting saturated when you use `sigmoid`.

Comment: Saturation on a network with a single hidden layer? That is not even a deep network. I think very unlikely. But still. Ill try and let you know.

Comment: And changing to relu did not work.

Comment: @AdityaShinde I didn't realize that yours was a single-layer network, my bad. I just observed that your lr is too high. How about starting with 0.01 and then decreasing it (say) after every 50 epochs or when the validation accuracy does not change for (say) 30 consecutive epochs.

Comment: Add a hidden layer to the network. Also try smaller batch sizes, as small as 32, [Here](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?s=20) is a discussion with a cited paper for why so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your learning rate is too high. you can try to set it to 0.0001

```
sgd=SGD(lr=0.0001)
```